# Read table from txt file in python

Tags: python

I've a problem with import of tables written in a txt report. The format of table is this:

```
"""
Ò         NDG  ANAGRAFICA             RAPPORTO        S.CONTABILE       FIDO BASE           STR.       FIDO PROP. F./SC.  INIZ.   GG.
Ò              STATUS               POSIZIONE
Ò           
Ò           
Ò   335647423  ERNESTORI MATTIO 03/045/23467890*             5,67            0,00           0,00            13,20  1/73 02/03/21    3
Ò             +RIENTRO SCAD/SCO
Ò           
Ò   567890432  PIAL MASSIMILI   23/345/12345678*           131,42-           0,00           0,00           124,34  1/34 06/03/21    1
"""
```

I use code like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep = '\s{2,}|\.\s{1,}', engine='python', skipinitialspace=True)
print(data)
```

But I have two problems:

**1.** Column header and content going to new line with spaces

EG:

```
ANAGRAFICA

STATUS


ERNESTORI MATTIO

+RIENTRO SCAD/SCO
```

**2.** Between columns I don't have a specific pattern. For example blank space is used as name separator under "Anagrafica" column.

How can I solve this with Python? Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Using end = "" in your print might help

Comment: @MojtabaValizadeh that won't change anything about how the file is read in and parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question. It seems that there are two observations to work with: 1) rows are separated by empty lines; 2) columns are aligned either left or right, but at set indices in the rows.
Using these two certainties one could use the following setup: 1) split the lines by index; 2) group the rows in the list of lists by whether they're separated by empty lists (rows); 3) join the strings in the groups for the same indexes:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby

data = """
Ò         NDG  ANAGRAFICA             RAPPORTO        S.CONTABILE       FIDO BASE           STR.       FIDO PROP. F./SC.  INIZ.   GG.
Ò              STATUS               POSIZIONE
Ò           
Ò           
Ò   335647423  ERNESTORI MATTIO 03/045/23467890*             5,67            0,00           0,00            13,20  1/73 02/03/21    3
Ò             +RIENTRO SCAD/SCO
Ò           
Ò   567890432  PIAL MASSIMILI   23/345/12345678*           131,42-           0,00           0,00           124,34  1/34 06/03/21    1
"""

#list of indices to split lines on
indices = [1,13,32,48,66,81,96,113,120,128,133]
#split lines by indices, generates a list of lists
text = [[s[i:j].strip() for i,j in zip(indices, indices[1:]+[None])] for s in data.splitlines()]
#group items in the list together 
text = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(text, key=lambda x: all('' == s for s in x)) if k == False]
#join elements in groups and strip trailing whitespaces
text = [[item.strip() for item in l] for l in [list(map(" ".join, zip(*i))) for i in text]]
df = pd.DataFrame(text[1:], columns=text[0])
```

Result:

|  | NDG | ANAGRAFICA STATUS | RAPPORTO POSIZIONE | S.CONTABILE | FIDO BASE | STR. | FIDO PROP. | F./SC. | INIZ. | GG. |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 335647423 | ERNESTORI MATTIO +RIENTRO SCAD/SCO | 03/045/23467890* | 5,67 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 13,20 | 1/73 | 02/03/21 | 3 |  |
| 1 | 567890432 | PIAL MASSIMILI | 23/345/12345678* | 131,42- | 0,00 | 0,00 | 124,34 | 1/34 | 06/03/21 | 1 |  |

Comment: Thenk you! This code solved my problem. Thank you!